# What are the UK tourist visa requirements for an Algerian citizen on an Irish work visa?

Tags: ireland, standard-visitor-visas, common-travel-area, algerian-citizens

When an Algerian citizen in Ireland on an Irish work visa wishes to visit the UK, say by air, on holiday, must he apply for a UK visa?

Comment: Yes. Despite the absence of border controls, it is unlawful for an Algerian to enter the UK without an entry clearance.  You can apply for one online and submit it in the ROI however.